# I need a better way to stop hackers from inserting fatal data into my database

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a guest book on my site. It is very basic. Recently I have been doubting whether my current method of sanitizing the input added to the database is secure enough. Here is the current snippet of the code that collects the data and sanitizes it:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$c_name=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($name));
$detail=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['detail']));
```

Then obviously I would send the data to the server and place them in the necessary tables. Is this way efficient or are there any security holes I should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: All `mysql_real_escape_string()` does is escape quotes. There are many other ways to "compromise" a site, including CSRF and XSS. You're best to just leave only what you allow, not *just* escape anything provided.

Comment: That's sufficient. Note that the condemning answers you got only point out that the approach is -amateurish-. But since you only ever want to print out the guestbooks entries again on your page, it is in fact -practical- to pre-escape the html content.

Comment: @mario - Are you directing that comment at me? I'm not sure what you mean either way.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: No. At the answers. While technically correct, I feel the simple approach OP has chosen (htmlspecialchars first) is more appropriate for him.

Comment: @mario After rethinking and reading some of the answers I really only need to use htmlspecialchars() when displaying output. Well the answer I'm referring to deleted their post.

Comment: @mario: Sure. Right up until you end up with "&quo" on your page somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use `htmlspecialchars()` on data you are sending to the database; it should *only* be used on output. Other than that, I recommend you read ["Making Wrong Code Look Wrong"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) so that you can keep your variables straight.

> ... making robust code by literally *inventing conventions* that make errors stand out on the screen.

Comment: The article you linked provides a lot of good ways to encode the data being sent or presented. Very interesting.